# Get distinct data from 2 tables using join

Tags: sql-server, join

Below is my query . I take socail sercurity no from Employee table and match it with child_excel table. Using that I get Employee ID and matching that with EmployeeCh table (which has employee ID). The employee has 2 child's so when I put the gender clause I get 4 records 2 for each child with different (i.e Male, Female) for each of the child's. I want only 2 rows for child 1 for each child with their respective genders.

```
SELECT distinct 
      [SSN],
      empch2.GenderID,
      gen.Name1
  FROM [child_excel] as t
  INNER JOIN Employee as empch on t.SSN = empch.SocialSecurityNo
  INNER JOIN EmployeeCh  as empch2 on empch.ID = empch2.EmployeeID  
  INNER JOIN Gender as gen on empch2.GenderID = gen.ID
```

I am getting O/p as

```
12345  1  Male
12345  2  Female
99999  1  Male
99999  2  Female
```

Expected output is

```
12345   1   Male
99999   2   Female
```

But when I add First Name in the join it gives proper output. I dnt want to use first Name

```
SELECT distinct 
          [SSN],
          empch2.GenderID,
          gen.Name1
      FROM [child_excel] as t
      INNER JOIN Employee as empch on t.SSN = empch.SocialSecurityNo
      INNER JOIN EmployeeCh  as empch2 on empch.ID = empch2.EmployeeID and  t.First_Name= empch2.FirstName  
      INNER JOIN Gender as gen on empch2.GenderID = gen.ID
```

Comment: SSN is not same. which SSN you want in grouping?

Comment: I want as many distinct records but only 1 record per unique rows.

Comment: Does not matter which row then?

Comment: I want O/P as 

12345   1   Male
99999   2   Female

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER ()

```
Select * from (

SELECT distinct 
      [SSN],
      empch2.GenderID,
      gen.Name1,
      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [SSN] ORDER BY empch2.GenderID)RN
  FROM [child_excel] as t
  INNER JOIN Employee as empch on t.SSN = empch.SocialSecurityNo
  INNER JOIN EmployeeCh  as empch2 on empch.ID = empch2.EmployeeID and  t.First_Name= empch2.FirstName  
  INNER JOIN Gender as gen on empch2.GenderID = gen.ID )T
  WHERE T.RN = 1
```

Comment: Here I am getting 1 record data time. I want as many distinct records.

Comment: but based on your sample data it gives correct result and distinct also @user2998990